Kotlin android use fusedLocationProviderClient for requestLocationUpdates. for commercial use
I do this and I can not find any information for my question can I do this for free in commercial project , it is any limitation ?
I try find any information in net but I can not find
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    TextView locationTextView;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
//Instantiating the Location request and setting the priority and the interval I need to update the location.
        locationRequest = locationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(50);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

//instantiating the LocationCallBack
        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult != null) {
                    if (locationResult == null) {
                        return;
                    }
     //Showing the latitude, longitude and accuracy on the home screen.
                    for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                        locationTextView.setText(MessageFormat.format("Lat: {0} Long: {1} Accuracy: {2}", location.getLatitude(),
                                location.getLongitude(), location.getAccuracy()));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
    }
}

Can I do this in commercial project for free it is any limitation ?

of course you can, tons of apps use it

Yes, the API provided by Google Play Services is free and can be used for commercial purposes.
For more information, you can refer to the following links:
API Overview: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview
Location Services: https://developers.google.com/location-context
